# QGIS Extract elevation data only for one country

Tags: qgis, raster, elevation, extract-by-mask

I have a map built with a shapefile for country contours and a raster from .hgt files with elevation representation. How can I only select the area corresponding to the country?

I found some thing for matlab [extract only the elevation of a country](http://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/66561-does-anyone-know-how-to-extract-only-the-elevation-of-a-country) but not in QGIS. I'm thinking of using a polygon, but I am not familiar with how to do so. Or in a subtraction of the outside, but how to determine that? On the image, the red lines show the parts I want to eliminate.

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to clip the raster?

Comment: Hum...I don't know the translation of "clip" , I try to explain : I want to get the raster of altitude only for the area given by  the shapefile (inside the borders,  it is Ethiopia). Perhaps is it clipping ?

Comment: Yes it is. Check Raster | Extraction | Clipper.

Comment: thanks exactly what I wanted ! QGis tricks begin to give their secret